# Bootstrap grid class dependent on item count

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I need to adjust grid items, depended on how many posts will be published from CMS.
There will be two options:

- 50% / 50% grid - two items per row if there is 2,4 posts
- 33% / 33% / 33% grid - if there are 3 or 6 posts

But how to make "if 2 posts use span6, if 3 posts use span4"?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can just modulus the length to check if the number of posts are even - by the sounds of it you may be able to simply use something like below (where `$posts` is a jQuery object of all the posts relevant to the grid):

```
if($posts.length % 2 === 0) {
   $posts.addClass("span6").removeClass("span4");
}
else {
    $posts.addClass("span4").removeClass("span6");
}
```

Or even simpler:

```
var even = $posts.length % 2 === 0;
$posts.toggleClass("span6", even).toggleClass("span4", !even);
```

Also you may want to consider upgrading to bootstrap 3.0 - there have been significant improvements to the grid system in the new version.

Comment: Thanks you, it looks promising. Yes, I'm using Bootstrap 3, is it doable in Bootstrap 3 without jQuery code?

Comment: `span6` and `span4` are bootstrap 2.0 classes. The near equivalents are `col-*-6` and `col-*-4`. I suggest you read this article on the grid system: http://www.helloerik.com/bootstrap-3-grid-introduction

Comment: Yes, sorry, I am aware of classes differences, it's just habit to still use terms "span" for columns. But I guess this grid system still need some jQuery to do what I want, right? + It will be a little more complicated because this website is responsive and I will be using col-md-, col-xl-, col-xs- classes.

Comment: Its unlikely you can solve this without some javascript as css doesn't support modulus - bootstrap doesn't have a complete css solution to your problem

Comment: In case of bootstrap 2.0 classes.. How come span6 or span4 and not span3 or span2? just curious

Comment: @CarlLindberg Theres 12 columns you have to fill so when you want only two columns to take the entire width you set each to size 6. When you want 3 columns you need to set each to `span4`